# Average complexity of an algorithm

Tags: algorithm, loops, time-complexity

My teacher gave me the below code to find out his average  complexity:

```
 int function(int a[], int n)
{
    int k=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
            k=k+((a[i]*a[i]+a[j]*a[j])%5==0)
    return k;
}
void main()
{
    int vector={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
    int a=function(vector, 10);
    printf( "%d\n", a);
}
```

By unrowling the loops I found out that the code executes `n*(n+1)/2` times and I conclude that the worst case is `O(n^2)`  because exists `n*(n+1)/2 < c*n^2` for `n>n0` .I know that the definition of average complexity is quite similar, but I found quite difficult to calculate it.I want to know what is the complexity in this case and if there are standardized methods for calculating these type of problems

( eg : nested loops with dependencies between the iterators).

Comment: This code always does the same amount of work, so the average case, best case, and worst-case should be the same.

Comment: @templatetypedef That was my guess also.But for my teacher I need a more elevated answer.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "more elevated," but just saying that the runtime only depends on the length and nothing else should suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In average case analysis, we take all possible inputs and calculate computing time for all of the inputs. Sum all the calculated values and divide the sum by total number of inputs.

There is only one possiblity in your algorithm. For **all inputs**, your algorithm runs in O(n*(n+1)/2) time.

Average time complexity is  O(n*(n+1)/2) = O(n^2).

Answer (score 2):

In computational complexity theory, the average-case complexity of an algorithm is the amount of some computational resource (typically time) used by the algorithm, averaged over all possible inputs [see here for definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average-case_complexity).

In your case, you have already figured out that your program will execute for n*(n+1)/2 (for a given n) times. Then you can think: what if n = 1, 2, 3, ...? You only need to add up all those values using your formula and take an average. It is easy to get the O(n^2) solution.